# Python neural network throws error for indexing

Tags: python, neural-network

My code is as follows

```
import scipy.io as sio
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

X=sio.loadmat('pyInput.mat')
y=sio.loadmat('pyTarget.mat')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

StandardScaler.fit(X_train)
X_train = StandardScaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = StandardScaler.transform(X_test)

mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(10,10,10))
mlp.fit(X_train,y_train)

predictions = mlp.predict(X_test)

print(confusion_matrix(y_test,predictions))
print(classification_report(y_test,predictions))
```

When I run this in spyder, my error is

`return [X[idx] for idx in indices]`

I tried defining x_train, x_test, y_train, and y_test manually by creating the proper split matrices myself in matlab. However, I then get an error that says

```
fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'\
```

for the StandardScaler.fit(X_train) part.

If I remove the StandardScaler part completely, then my error is

```
float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'
```

That error comes from a line in the validation.py file within Anaconda's packages, and the specific line is 402.

```
array=array.astype(np.float64)
```

My matrices (when not manually split) are 100x200 and the target is 100x1.

Comment: Is that the entire snippet? I don't see a line that lines up with your `return`. It looks like you are missing an opening bracket ('[') for the comprehension... e.g. `return [X[idx] for idx in indices]`

Comment: Sorry; I missed the bracket in front of the X, but what you just put is the entire error:

Comment: Ok, please edit your post to include it. The code that you posted doesn't include that line - please add that too! Hard to debug if we can't see the relevant bits.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it